# knex json array of object where condition

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js

I have a json array (composition) in my db and i need to make conditions

[
{
"name": "Rock",
"prices": [
{
"price": 400,
"duration": 40
}
],
"description": "Hello",
"nb_musicians": 40
}
]

And i try something like this but dont work

```
      .where(qb => {
    if (nbMusicians) {
      qb.whereRaw(
        `composition->
      '$.nb_musicians' = ?`,
        [40],
      );
    }
  })
```

Thanks for help